# What's the correct way to resize CALayers in a UIView Subclass?

Tags: swift, uiview, calayer, cashapelayer

I have a subclassed UIView which uses a CAShapeLayer to mask one of its subviews. Initially I ran into some problems when I used auto layout and realized that the CAShapelayer was not resizing. A working solution I found was to resize the child view in layoutSubviews() and remake the CAShapelayer. Is there a better solution in terms of performance or accepted design?

Comment: Have you tried making yourself the delegate of the layer and implementing layoutSublayersOfLayer ?

Comment: Sorry @GlennHowes, but how to do that, I don't see any examples. I have similar issue.

Comment: Well, it's been a while since my comment, but the general idea would be to declare your view as implementing CALayerDelegate, and then in some convenient place set your views delegate to yourself as in self.layer.delegate = self and then implement  optional public func layoutSublayers(of layer: CALayer) .  At least I think it would work.